# Visual Studio 2013 crashing on start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2013

I have just installed VS 2013 pro on a new laptop and when I try and open an existing project or create a new one, it fails to load. I then open it in a new version of the debugger and get these errors.

With opening an existing project I get

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll
Try one of the following options: - Change existing PDB and binary search paths and retry
```

When I try and create a new project I get a similar error

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.dll
    Try one of the following options: - Change existing PDB and binary search paths and retry
```

I also noticed that VS is creating the solution folder and the .sln file in the folder above it, but then nothing, the solution folder is empty after the crash

I have no idea why this might be happening but seems something to do with the install or maybe path information getting mixed up from a previous install. (It had VS 2013 shell installed before I installed 2013 pro)

Any thoughts?

Comment: try disabling extensions until it works

Comment: Clean start, yes. Will try disabling extensions now

Comment: Seems I can't disable anything. Could this be related to running without local admin rights?

Comment: or it could be that the extensions need to be removed from the Programs and Features Pane.  devenv.exe /SafeMode will load VS without any Third Party extensions, try this to rule out extensions being the issue.

Comment: I tried with safe mode, still the same error when I try and create a new project

Comment: Try reparing the installation

Comment: Have you tried Targetting different .Net Framework versions when creating a new project? Using the dropdown on the New Project window, does it error on all of them?  This way you can determine if its the .Net Framework version at fault and reinstall.

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately I tried it with no result. I did notice that the solution folder and the .sln file are both created but nothing within the solution folder. So it is getting as far as creating those and then crashing out

Answer (score 0):

Take a back up of your code. Just try to delete .pdb files and reload the projects.
Give it a try.

Comment: I don't actually have any project I'm trying to load yet, just trying to create a new blank template project

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some people [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f48c152-68cd-45ec-a11e-baa7de7f79c3/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory?forum=csharpgeneral) solved this by changing this setting:

```
Tools menu ->Options -> Debugging -> General -> Uncheck this option "Suppress JIT optimization on module load"
```

Other suggestions on that link:

1. Try turning on all optimizations, run the program under the debugger, and see if the error occurs. (Typically all optimizations are turned off in debug mode so that debugging is easier.) This will at least give you a way to reproduce the error when you have more debug information. This honestly won't help you a whole lot because by the time you crash, the method call that corrupted the memory is long gone.
2. Look at all unmanaged code that you're calling: COM objects, C/C++ DLLs, Win32 calls, etc. Check the P/Invoke signatures and COM interop thunks for all unmanaged code to verify that they're correct. Don't trust P/Invoke signatures that you find on the 'net. They're not always correct. Verify for yourself that your data types and parameter orderings are correct.
3. Try removing the unmanaged code (stub out the calls) and see if the problem goes away. If it does, investigate the component to verify that it is free of memory leaks. (Note that you might only be masking the problem as you re-arrange code.)
4. Try running your code under a unmanaged memory checker like Compuware BoundsChecker, which will look for memory leaks and access violations. This will likely give you some hints as to which unmanaged component is misbehaving.